# Overlapping null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$, $B\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$, $M>N$. $\dim(N(A)) = \dim(N(B)) = M-N$. Obviously the null spaces intersect:
$$\dim(N(A)\cap N(B)) = \dim(N(A))+\dim(N(B))-\dim(N(A)+N(B))=M-2N$$ 
the two null spaces overlap in $M-2N$ dimensions, This means there $N$ non-overlapping dimensions in each null space since $\dim(N(A)) = \dim(N(B)) = M-N$

How can I find these non-overlapping basis in each null space and is it possible that they can be orthogonal to the overlapping/intersecting dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

In the statement of your question there seems to be a few unjustified claims. First, why is it obvious that the nullspaces intersect...of course we always have $0 \in N(A) \cap N(B)$, but here I am referring to intersect in the sense of including other non-zero vectors. Now, secondly, why should $\dim(N(A)\cap N(B))=M-2N$? Suppose $M=3$ and $N=2$, then we would have $\dim(N(A)\cap N(B))=3-4=-1$ which is not possible.

Anyway, apart from these observations, I think it is best to determine the nullspace for each matrix (in the usual way by solving the homogenous system associated with each matrix) and then to check whether each of the basis vectors for one space is in the span of the other space's basisvectors.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should've clarified the question a little more and put the exact dimensions of the matrices ($M>>N$ here). I've already computed the intersection between the two null spaces and found they overlap in $M-2N$ dimensions.

Comment: Maybe we can give more specific help if you include the actual matrices you are working with....